# silverlight-4 com-interop Cannot invoke a non-delegate type

Tags: silverlight-4.0, com-interop, wsh

This silverlight code throws an error "Cannot invoke a non-delegate type"

```
        var WshShell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
        var WshSysEnv = WshShell.Environment("SYSTEM");
        var foo = WshSysEnv("APPDATA");
```

How can I get the environment variable?

**EDIT:** 
@paulsm4 - this works in silverlight...

```
        var WshShell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
        var appData = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%");
        MessageBox.Show(appData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming WSH, How about something like this:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%APPDATA%" )
wshShell = Nothing
```